# What do DoEvents()'s in C# actually do?

Tags: c#, multithreading, vb6

We hired a company to convert an old VB6 DLL which controls some industrial machinery to C#.     The old VB6 code had "pause" routines consisting of sleep calls sprinkled with **DoEvents** so that while sleeping, timer and socket events in the DLL would still get processed.  The DoEvents were converted to

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
```

I'm not a VB6 programmer but my understanding is that VB6 is actually single-threaded and so a long sleep would shut down everything including timer and socket event handling.

When the code was converted to C# the pause routines looked like this . . .

```
public static void pauseit_ms(ref int milliseconds)
{
    try
    {
        Sleep(milliseconds / 2);
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
        Sleep(milliseconds / 2);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        LogException("pauseit_ms", exc);
    }
}
```

In .Net, timer and socket events run in their own threads (most of my work in this converted code has been to try to make it thread-safe!) so it's not obvious what the **DoEvents()** buys us.  But the MSDN says

> Calling this method causes the current thread to be suspended while
>   all waiting window messages are processed.

So should we leave these **DoEvents()** in so other kinds of events (not timer or socket callbacks) aren't blocked?  Or are they superfluous in a .Net/C# context?

Comment: FYI, `DoEvents` is not part of C#. It's part of the .NET Framework.

Comment: Sounds like the company you hired did a 1 for 1 conversion without caring for how the code actually works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`DoEvents` creates an additional message loop.  It's just a loop that reads in a message, processes it, and then reads in the next message, until it gets a message that it should stop, or has no messages to process.  Calling `Application.Run` creates the initial message loop for your application.  Creating additional nested messages loops from within one of the handlers for these messages can cause [all sorts of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5181777/1159478) and so it should be avoided unless you're intimately familiar with what it does and under what circumstances you can use it correctly.

For the most part, rather than creating an additional message loop, your program should simply be asyncrhonous.  Rather than blocking the current thread for a period of time, you should be using something like a `Timer` to execute a method after a period of time *without blocking the current thread*.

> In .Net, timer and socket events run in their own threads

The actual waiting for the Timer's time to elapse, or for the socket to get a response, is done *without the use of any thread at all*.  There is no thread sitting there sleeping, rather the operations are inherently asynchronous.  As for the thread that is used to execute the event handlers, that will vary.  Some Timers will use a thread pool, some the UI thread, and some are configurable and can do either.  The socket is likely going to just be using a thread pool thread.

Comment: "If there are no messages it will just wait until it gets one." - Is this about `DoEvents`? If so, this does not ring true. `DoEvents` does not wait for messages; it processes all it finds, then exits when there are none left. (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262728(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: This isn't true with regard to "creating" an additional message loop. All that `DoEvents` does is re-enter the existing message loop.

Answer (score 6):

VB6 DoEvents suspends processing of the current procedure (which is the only way this can happen), processes all messages in the application message queue (so events may fire), thus making your procedure reentrant. It then calls Windows API function Sleep(0). Windows then does it's message stuff. At the end of it your procedure is restarted.

The good thing is that while you get the problems of multithreading, you are still single threaded, so simple code like `If InProc = True then Exit Function:InProc = True:...:InProc = False:End Function` will work as it can't be preempted half way through.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you don't want to use `Application.DoEvents()`. A bad practice example of how it can be used would be to make sure your cursor changes to the wait cursor before continuing with a long running operation on the same thread (the operation should really run on a separate thread).

```
 Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
 //Makes sure this change takes effect instead of being blocked by the next line. 
 //NOT SUPER RELIABLE
 Application.DoEvents();

 //Do long work here
 Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
```

In your specific case, it looks like they are trying to use it as a hack to fake the UI being a little more responsive than it actually is.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this in a loop instead:

```
await System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Yield()
```

> Creates an awaitable object that asynchronously yields control back to
>   the current dispatcher and provides an opportunity for the dispatcher
>   to process other events.

It's much nicer and essentially creates lazy loading of UI for you.

Answer (score -1):

`*Processes all Windows messages currently in the message queue.*`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

It allows Window Forms to process any messages waiting for it from the Window Message Pump. 
So all your code does it wait half the time it is asked, then process messages and wait again.